# Proving that Linear Integral Operator is strongly positive.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Here is a problem I'm solving:[image]

**Is Strongly Positive.**

I actually managed to prove this.(If someone is interested, I can provide the link) But my proof is really long and it's based on the assumption that K(x,y) is symmetric and hence self-adjoint.
I wonder if there is another proof that does not use my assumption so I could use the operator for non-symmetric kernels?
I would appreciate any advice!
Here is the setup for the operator. I need to prove that the operator is strongly positive to be able to use it in this setup, using Krein-Rutman theorem and one more theorem that establishes uniqueness of a simple eigenvalue with the positive eigenvector.
[image]

Comment: What is $R$?  What do you mean by "strongly positive"?

Comment: R is just a positive constant. Strongly positive means that it belongs to the interior of a solid cone.

Comment: Which solid cone?

Comment: I added the setup for this operator and explanation about the cone with some additional information.

Comment: You still didn't say what cone you want your operator to be in.

Comment: Do you mean $T(f) \ge 0$ on $[0,1]$ whenever $f \ge 0$ on $[0,1]$?  That's obvious...

Comment: Hi, the theorem does not specify this. But in my case I need it to be in a solid cone, formed by nonnegative functions on C([0,1]). And I cant have T(f) more or equal to zero. It has to be more than zero.

Comment: Edit: In the interior of a solid cone.

Answer (score 1):

If $k \in C([0,1] \times [0,1])$ and $k(x,y) > 0$ for all $x,y$, then 
there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $k(x,y) \ge \epsilon$ for all $x,y$.
Now if $f \in C[0,1]$ with $f \ge 0$, $$Tf(x) = R \int_0^1 k(x,y) f(y)\; dy \ge R\epsilon \int_0^1 f(y)\; dy$$
(and this is best possible, in the sense that it's an equality if $k(x,y)$ 
is constant).  Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks. In this case it still depends on function f though...I'll have to work on that a little more. But still, Thank you for your help!